# Objective c keyboard opens unwillingly

Tags: ios, uiview, keyboard, uitextfield, uitextview

I have a "layer builder" object which creates different views and returns them after initialising them.

The problem is, whenever i press on one of these created views, the keyboard opens up and i can't understand why.

This is how my layer builder is coded:

```
@interface LayerBuilder : NSObject <VENTokenFieldDelegate, VENTokenFieldDataSource, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

the VEN stuff is a project i found on [github](https://github.com/venmo/VENTokenField) which i'm using, it has text fields used in it in case it matters.

And an example for layer builder usage:

```
-(void) showEmailCompilationView
{
    lb = [[LayerBuilder alloc] init];
    [lb placeDetailsLayerOnView:self.view withContacts:TRUE withSubject:TRUE withLable:@"Mail"];
    ...
}
```

and the function being called:

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

int xOrig = screenRect.origin.x;
int yOrig = screenRect.origin.y;
int xWid = screenRect.size.width;

int yWid = TEXT_FIELD_HEIGHT;

if(ctcs)
{
    yWid += TEXT_FIELD_HEIGHT + TEXT_VIEW_BOUNDRIES * 2;
}

if(subject)
{
    yWid += TEXT_FIELD_HEIGHT + TEXT_VIEW_BOUNDRIES * 2;
}

UIView* viewToAdd = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(xOrig, yOrig, xWid, yWid)];

viewToAdd.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

[view addSubview:viewToAdd];

return viewToAdd;
}
```

Nothing fancy as you see.

Now, whenever i press this layer, the keyboard is opened regardless of the fact that this layer is a simple `uiview` which has nothing to do with the keyboard.

Any idea on where the problem lays?

Comment: i've not used the VEN stuff, but my guess would be that the text field is becoming the first responder. Try and resign the first responder from the text field, or assign it elsewhere. Also, if possible remove the VEN protocol assignments from your LayerBuilder class declaration and see if the keyboard still opens. This will at least help you identify if the VEN stuff is the culprit.

Comment: @MDB983 but the layer im building doe's not include any VEN stuff. it just creates a UIVIEW and that's it. nothing more. it seems like the returned view should not open any keyboard. and i removed it from the class declaration, still happens

Comment: As mentioned the keyboard opens when a uitextview becomes the first responder. Now, I dotice you are casting a uitextview as a uiview, perhaps this is your issue, is there a reason you are doing this?

Comment: @MDB983 THANKS!!! i did by mistake i guess, most have been a copy paste thing from somewhere. you nailed it :D 
care writing this as an answer so that i will be able to accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formalized Comment;

Casting UITextField as UIView is causing the keyboard to open.

Thanks